# VS Code can not run non-Spring Maven project correctly

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

*I must apologize if it is a duplicate question, but I googled first without getting a useful answer.*

### Description

Today I'm trying to migrate from IDEA to VS Code, but when running a non-spring Maven project in VS Code, it won't run with dependencies in pom.xml, I can only get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` in console.

### Here I'll provided a brief example:

The project shown below use fastjson to parse a Map to JSON string, the fastjson is a maven repository defined in `pom.xml`.

#### Project Structure

[image: Project Structure]

#### App.java

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
        item.put("a", "1");
        item.put("b", "2");
        System.out.println(JSON.toJSONString(item));
    }
}
```

#### pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>

  <name>demo</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.78</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

#### Maven Dependencies Shown in VS Code

[image: Maven Dependencies]

#### Try to run the project with `Run and Debug` in VS Code

[image: Run and Debug]

#### Result

[image: Result]
Look! The VS Code did not run this Maven project correctly, it did not run with dependencies in pom.xml!

### Trivia

1. I have installed `Extension Pack for Java` for VS Code
2. I even installed `Spring Boot Extension Pack` for VS Code
3. I have installed Maven and configured corresponding Environment Variable, `mvn` command is able to run in console
4. The project above is running correctly in IDEA
5. Spring project is able to run normally in VS Code, but the problem project is maven without Spring

### Help

Did I miss some configurations for VS Code to run Maven project? What should I do to make it running correctly in VS Code?

Comment: The class you have defined `import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;` simply does not exist...which means it's not available from the given dependency...

Comment: @khmarbaise No, it exists, I just use it here as an example, you can change it to any other maven dependencies and you will find you can't run with them in VS Code, too. And I said this sample project is viable to run in IDEA. It is nothing to do with this fastjson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved my problem with VS Code myself. I put my solution here in case someone or I met the same problem in the future.

##### To solve the issue:

1. I moved my maven dependencies path to else where: I created a folder `G:\maven-repo`, and modified global `settings.xml` of maven like below:

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>G:/maven-repo</localRepository>
</settings>
```

2. In `settings.json` of VS Code, I added the line below, which refers to where the `settings.xml` in step 1 is:

```
"java.configuration.maven.globalSettings": "G:/ideaIU/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/conf/settings.xml"
```

3. Restart VS Code, execute `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` as @Molly Wang-MSFT said.
4. After restarting VS Code again, pressing the F5 key, the project finally runs correctly.
   [image: correctly]

Answer (score 1):

Your code throws no errors in my project:

[image]

I think there's a cache messed it, you may

1. Turn to local dependency installation folder, delete `\User folder\.m2\repository\com\alibaba\fastjson\1.2.78`
2. Delete the dependency `fastjson` in `pom.xml`
3. Open Command Palette and choose **Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace**
4. re-add the `fastjson` dependency and follow the notification to synchronize project configuration.

Comment: I think something went wrong with my VS Code Installed on my PC, when I change to another PC, it works! I think I had better re-install my vscode.... Thanks for your help

Comment: @Paper_Folding. Then you can [reset VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-can-i-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-vs-code)